# Bluescreen whenever i ping my own ip-address instead of localhost

Tags: ajax, wcf, windows-7

I build an application which use *ajax calls* for posting and getting data from *wcf service*. The *wcf service* is published on my *IIS service*. Whenever I put *localhost* in the app config file, the application runs okey, I get and post all the data I need, but if I put the *IP-address* that represents the *localhost*, the windows is crashing, it goes to blue screen error.

**`Error info:`**

`Problem signature:`

- Windows 7
- OS version 6.1.7601
- Locale ID: 1071

`Addictional information about the problem:`

- BCCode: d1
- BCP1: 000000001C220743
- BCP2: 0000000000000002
- BCP3: 0000000000000000
- BCP3: FFFFF8800670F21A
- OS Version: 6_1_7601
- Service Pack: 1_0
- Product: 256_1

Also, when I start the application from another computer (computer that is in the same domain as mine), and use my IP address there, than my computer do not crash, the problem happens just when I use my own IP address on my own computer instead of 'localhost'

Comment: Are you running any local firewall (Windows built-in or other)?

Comment: The firewall is turned off.

Comment: Does this also happen if you use the loopback interface address 127.0.0.1?